# Olingo OData response to JSON

Tags: olingo

The returned type of a response of a request is ClientEntitySetIterator

1. What is the simplest way to convert a response to a JSON string ?
2. Query builder is getting complex and maintenance issue when we have more joins. What is the simplest way to define when we have huge joins to be added as part of the query?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code?

Comment: ODataRetrieveResponse<ClientEntitySetIterator<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity>> response = request.execute();
ClientEntitySetIterator<ClientEntitySet, ClientEntity>  iterator = response.getBody();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
}